# KEY_ENTER vs '\n'?

Tags: c++, newline, curses, pdcurses

When I'm using PDcurses and I try to have a while loop exit when the enter key is pressed with `while(key != KEY_ENTER)`, the while loop never exits. However, when I try to have the same loop exit with `while((char)key != '\n')`, it exits successfully whenever I pressed enter. Why does `'\n'` work and not `KEY_ENTER`?

btw, `key` is an int

and I hope this is the relevant few lines of the code:

```
int key;
while((char)key != '\n') {
    key = getch();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getch()` is a function defined by the ANSI C standard for the C runtime library.

On most systems, such as Windows, Linux, etc., this function is implemented to return `'\n'` when the user pressed Enter.  For Comparison, on Windows the key-press itself (of Enter) might be represented as the key-code `VK_ENTER`.

PDCurses is translating the key codes to ASCII values for you.

You can get the key values you want if you first call the PDCurses functions `raw(); nonl();`.  Also, you should probably use `wgetch()` for new code.

Comment: what are the benefits of using `wgetch()`?

Comment: getch() is a macro which conflicts with the C standard function of that name.  wgetch(WINDOW *) won't conflict.  You can make your own replacement macro if you like the lack of argument, perhaps call it getkey() or getcursed().

Comment: Another problem with `getch()` and using int for chars is unicode. You can't represent all possible characters a user might input in an int, and getch() is from ASCII days.

Comment: @Stephen - I thought so at first, but I'm not sure what curses getch() would return.

Comment: Where is `getch()` defined in the standard exactly? I've never seen it.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt : `getch` was never part of the standard library. [However, it was included in `conio.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)

Answer (score 2):

```
KEY_ENTER == 0x157, '\n' == 0xA
```

'\n' is the standard ASCII newline, while KEY_ENTER represents a keyboard code.  See [the PDCurses code](http://pdcurses.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdcurses/PDCurses/curses.h?view=markup).

For more information, you should post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Because after you pressed enter, `key == '\n'`.  It can't equal two things at once.  You should post your code if you want more help.

Comment: I don't get how `key` being an `int` (so it can't equal `'\n'` at any time, right?) does not equal `KEY_ENTER` after a key is pressed, but `(char)key` does equal `\n`

Comment: Yes, an int can equal a character constant.  Try `int c = 10; if(c == '\n') { doSomething(); }`